# Make sure function is called only once, either in componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to make sure that a function is called exactly one time, depending on some props and state.

```js
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    externalInfoPresent: false,
    infoSaved: false,
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.refreshExternalInfo();
    this.setState({ externalInfoPresent: true });
    if (this.props.externalInfo !== undefined && !this.state.infoSaved) {
      await this.saveMyInfo();
    }
  }

  async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.externalInfo === this.props.externalInfo || this.state.infoSaved) return;
    await this.saveMyInfo();
  }

  async saveMyInfo() {
    if (this.props.externalInfo === undefined || this.state.infoSaved) return;
    // logic for saving stuff to external service
    this.setState({ infoSaved });
  }

  // render and other stuff
}
```

`saveMyInfo()` depends on `externalInfo` being present.

I would like `saveMyInfo()` to only be called once but it's being called twice with my current logic.

Comment: There's always a chance the component updates while `componentDidMount` is still waiting for `refreshExternalInfo` or `refreshExternalInfo` causes the props to update and therefore cause `componentDidUpdate` to be called. I'm not too clear as to what is exactly happening with this code because it's incomplete but it is worth considering this

Comment: @apokryfos - yes, that is what is currently happening and I don't have a good solution for this:) I just added that `saveMyInfo()` depends on `externalInfo` being present which I omitted originally.

Comment: Does `refreshExternalInfo` change the props? If it does then maybe only keep the save in `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: Yes, `refreshExternalInfo` can change the props. Not always though, only if `this.props.externalInfo === undefined` and if I only keep it in `componentDidUpdate` I can run into a situation when `saveMyInfo()` doesn't get call at all.

Answer (score 6):

If you want it to be called only once, then componentDidMount is the place (it gets called exactly once in the lifecycle). Therefore you don't need it in ComponentDidUpdate (which gets called everytime a prop changes (after the initial render)!

Lifecycle: https://hackernoon.com/reactjs-component-lifecycle-methods-a-deep-dive-38275d9d13c0

Updated..

I think you Just need to set infosaved to true (this.setstate({infosaved:true}) after you call savemyinfo in componentdidupdate.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, but saveMyInfo needs `externalInfo` to be present.

Comment: So in this case if we don't have `externalInfo` it won't be called at all in componentDidMount, right ?

Comment: Right - ive updated my answer. I think you just need to set infoSaved to prevent it being called again.

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional flag:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    externalInfoPresent: false,
    infoSaved: false,
    saveMyInfoCalled: false,
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.refreshExternalInfo();
    this.setState({ externalInfoPresent: true });
    if (this.props.externalInfo !== undefined && !this.state.infoSaved) {
      await this.saveMyInfo();
    }
  }

  async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.externalInfo !== undefined && !this.state.saveMyInfoCalled && !this.state.infoSaved) {
      await this.saveMyInfo();
    }
  }

  async saveMyInfo() {
    this.setState({saveMyInfoCalled: true});
    if (this.props.externalInfo === undefined || this.state.infoSaved) return;
    // logic for saving stuff to external service
  }

  // render and other stuff
}
```

You probably should call `this.setState({saveMyInfoCalled: false});` somewhere if external service fails. So `saveMyInfo` doesn't get called several times simultaneously but has a second chance if something goes wrong.

Comment: Ah, I am already doing `this.setState({ infoSaved });` in `saveMyInfo() `. Forgot to add that *important* piece. will update.

Comment: You don't need to use state for this. State will cause a re-render. Just a simple boolean on the class will work fine.

Comment: You probably update `infoSaved` sometime after the call. So it might not prevent another simultaneous call. You should raise some flag immediately at the beginning of `saveMyInfo`.

Comment: @AlexK I tried using a boolean on the class too, the effect is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.refreshExternalInfo();
    await this.saveMyInfo();
  }

  async componentDidUpdate() {
    await this.saveMyInfo();
  }

  async saveMyInfo() {
    // if we don't have the info then skip for now
    if (this.props.externalInfo === undefined || this.infoSaved) return;

    // keep track that we already saved
    this.infoSaved = true;

    // perform save
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work and removing those guard clauses from `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount`  calls it 3 times.

Comment: Yes saveMyInfo is called each time but it will exit early if it's already been run.